# Clickable Text To Replace Radio buttons

Tags: css, forms, html

Hey guys Im trying to get some assistance brainstorming.

I have this Contact form on a site, That has Selectable text in place of something like checkboxes or radio buttons

Im using formidable forms I got the styles right with the radio buttons but it just doesnt have the same flare having just the text

Ill attach some images just to show for context, As im not sure what youd call this or what to really lookup to do more extensive research about this.

This is my Design on the site currently

[image]

This was the design

[image]

Im sure you can agree the selectable without the radio buttons just looks better, And as I mentioned I have no idea what the "Term" for this or howd go about this

```
<div class="frm_radio" id="frm_radio_18-0">
 <label for="field_yhi3q-0">        
  <input type="radio" name="item_meta[18]" id="field_yhi3q-0" value="WEB 
 DESIGN &amp; DEVELOPMENT" data-invmsg="I would like to talk to you about 
 is invalid">
 WEB DESIGN &amp; DEVELOPMENT
 </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an css question, so really this is not the right place for it.

However, you need to use the + operator and the :checked selector like this:

(This assumes your radio buttons are built like this):

```
<input type="radio" id="my_awesome_radio_1" value="value1" />
<label for="my_awesome_radio_1">Value 1</label>
<input type="radio" id="my_awesome_radio_2" value="value2" />
<label for="my_awesome_radio_2">Value 2</label>
<input type="radio" id="my_awesome_radio_3" value="value3" />
<label for="my_awesome_radio_3">Value 3</label>
```

CSS-Code:

```
input[type=radio] {
   display:none;
}

input[type=radio] + label {
   display: inline-block;
   border: 1px solid #eee;
   padding: 10px;
   margin-right: 10px;
   color: #eee;
}

input[type=radio]:checked + label {
   background: #eee;
   color: #000;
}
```

Comment: Apologies i'll make sure to post on stack instead then, But I did update my Qeustion with the Structure the form generate's, Would this allow for the form to actually pickup on the Input so that when the mail gets sent that The selection is actually. made as it seems to me that the radio buttons will disappear but the  how would the selection happen

Comment: I do see what you mean however this does work but my selections dont work then and if i just set the opacity the space is still taken

Comment: Ah I resolved it by just Removing the margins/padding/ Widths and heights of the radios and then just setting the opacity to 0